# Pandas unable to parse comma separated file correctly

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am trying to parse a CSV file, but somehow pandas does not recognize the separator/delimiter. I have look at the similar replies around, but I still have not managed to parse my file correctly (only the header is parsed properly).

Each line of the file looks like this: `https://drive.google.com/a/company.com/uc?export=download&id=10p-c0i2xtWBSvJ3OJV5pgEUarE1X,-1,"{""type"":""F03""}",0,0,"{}","{}"`

The code I have tried is following:

```
In  [0]: import pandas as pd

In  [1]: data = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=',')
         data.head()
Out [1]: 

    filename          file_size   file_attributes    region_count    region_id   region_shape_attributes  region_attributes
0   https://drive...        NaN               NaN             NaN          NaN                       NaN                NaN
1   https://drive...        NaN               NaN             NaN          NaN                       NaN                NaN
2   https://drive...        NaN               NaN             NaN          NaN                       NaN                NaN
3   https://drive...        NaN               NaN             NaN          NaN                       NaN                NaN
4   https://drive...        NaN               NaN             NaN          NaN                       NaN                NaN

In  [2]: data['filename'][0]
Out [2]: 

'https://drive.google.com/a/company.com/uc?export=download&id=10p-c0i2xtWBSvJ3OJV5pgEUarE1X,-1,"{""type"":""F03""}",0,0,"{}","{}"'
```

Comment: are the quotes part of that line? Since then that is logical, since it means the entire row is one string.

Comment: No, they are not. They are added by pandas when trying to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I did not manage to reproduce your issue. However, you can parse the columns from `data` data frame by the following piece of code.

```
df = data[['filename']]
cols_to_extract = [
    'filename', 'file_size', 'file_attributes', 'region_count', 
    'region_id', 'region_shape_attributes', 'region_attributes']
df[cols_to_extract] = pd.DataFrame(df['filename'].str.split(',').tolist(), columns=cols_to_extract)
df.head()
```

Output should look like this:

```
    file_name           file_size   file_attributes       region_count  region_id   region_shape_attributes  region_attributes
0   https://drive...          -1    "{""type"":""F03""}"             0          0   "{}"                     "{}"
1   https://drive...          -1    "{""type"":""F03""}"             0          0   "{}"                     "{}"
2   https://drive...          -1    "{""type"":""F03""}"             0          0   "{}"                     "{}"
3   https://drive...          -1    "{""type"":""F03""}"             0          0   "{}"                     "{}"
4   https://drive...          -1    "{""type"":""F03""}"             0          0   "{}"                     "{}"
```

I hope it will be helpful.